# How to highlight all the div between 2 selected divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Let's say I have 10 div: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10... and I have selected div 2 and div 7. Now what is need is, as soon as I select my ending div after my starting div (starting div=2 and ending div=7), all the div between these two will get highlighted.

What I have done till now is I can select any 2 divs and both gets selected and highlighted(which is done using css). Now the thing I want is to highlight all the time slots between 2 terminals

```
              <div *ngFor="let todayDate of dates; let z = index" class="dateBox">
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">{{fullDate[z] | date: 'fullDate'}}</div>
                        <div class="" *ngFor="let time of ScheduleTime; let i = index">
                            <div *ngIf="todayDate == time.date">
                                <div class="timeSlots" [ngClass]="{'startClass': time.hours == st.sh && time.minutes == st.sm && startDate == time.date, 'endClass': time.hours == et.eh && time.minutes == et.em && startDate == time.date}" (click)='timeSelector(time,i,todayDate)'>
                                    {{time.hours}}:{{time.minutes | zero}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div
                    </div>
```

I have the index of both the selected divs, Can it be used to fulfil what I am seeking for.

Comment: can you put your code in :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular fork and post link

Comment: just use two variables startSelect & endSelect and use `[style.background-color]="startSelect>0 && endSelect>0 && z>startSelect && z<=endSelect?'yellow':null"`. Take account put startSelect and endSelect variables to -1 at first or if you are selecting the fist row

Comment: @Eliseo I am getting your logic but it is not working. I am assuming we have to write that line of code in <div class="timeSlots"....>. Correct ?

Comment: I don't know if you want some thing like https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c93ysr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts (the code in the comment is wrong, you need include <= and >= you need use "i", not "z" and you need take account of z

Answer (score 0):

You can use also CSS rules for that. `selected_div ~ div`(or selector your need).
Selected_div can be :nth-child or just add custom class. Then `lastSelected_div ~ div`(for rest divs with default style).

Comment: Can u please help me by providing code. I am not getting how to write the thing